# How to load external Angular 7 application pages in ASP.NET Webforms aspx page in existing application?

Tags: .net, angular, webforms

I have requirement to load the pages of the external angular 7 application inside the existing .net web form application ?

Answer (score 0):

If the Angular components are relatively small, you can use the new feature "Angular Elements" (https://angular.io/guide/elements).  This allows you to package up your Angular app into custom web components that can be dropped into an HTML5 page.  There is a good blog post of how to implement it here (https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6-52c0b3076c2c).  Please note that this is not supported in IE11.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for loading the entire angular pages into the .net webform page